# Image Slider is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I want my javascript to work separately with both id="wrapper" and  id="wrapper2" but it is not doing so.....i really don't know what to do next pls help...is i am doing something wrong or i have to make different javascripts for my different image sliders on same page. or any editing in this code will help??

```
<div id="wrapper">

            <div class="slides">
                <img src="slide1/1.jpeg" alt="image" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </div>    
            <div class="slides">
                <img src="slide1/2.jpeg" alt="image" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slides">
                <img src="slide1/3.jpeg" alt="image" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </div>

            <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(1)" id="btn1">&#10094</button>
            <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(-1)" id="btn2">&#10095</button>

    </div>
    <div id="wrapper2">

            <div class="slides">
                <img src="slide2/1.jpeg" alt="image" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </div>    
            <div class="slides">
                <img src="slide2/2.jpeg" alt="image" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </div>
            <div class="slides">
                <img src="slide2/3.jpeg" alt="image" width="100%" height="100%"/>
            </div>

            <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(1)" id="btn1">&#10094</button>
            <button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(-1)" id="btn2">&#10095</button>

    </div>
```

here is the javascript

```
var index = 1;

        function plusIndex(n){
            index = index + n;
            showImage(index);
        }


        showImage(index);

        function showImage(n){
            var i;
            var x = document.getElementsByClassName("slides");
            if(n > x.length){
                index = 1;
            }
            if(n <=0 ){
                index = x.length;
            }
            for(i=0; i<x.length;i++){
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            x[index - 1].style.display = "block";
        }
```

Comment: Can you improve this statement so that it makes sense: "I want my javascript to work separately with both and but it is not doing so" ?. If something is ungrammatical, that's acceptable (but it still should be corrected), but if it's not possible to understand it needs to be fixed.

Comment: well some of my text is not getting posted i don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html put the class name of the wrapper in your plusIndex call, thus:

```
<button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(1, 'wrapper')" id="btn1">&#10094</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(-1, 'wrapper')" id="btn2">&#10095</button>
```

and

```
<button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(1, 'wrapper2')" id="btn1">&#10094</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="plusIndex(-1, 'wrapper2')" id="btn2">&#10095</button>
```

Then in the js, keep an associative array for index, not a single number, thus:

```
var indexes = {'wrapper': 1, 'wrapper2': 1};
```

then the rest is easy:

```
function plusIndex(n, id){
            indexes[id] += n;
            showImage(indexes[id], id);
        }

        function showImage(n, id){
            var i;
            var el = document.getElementById(id);
            var x = el.querySelector('slides');
            if(n > x.length){
                indexes[id] = 1;
            }
            if(n <=0 ){
                indexes[id] = x.length;
            }
            for(i=0; i<x.length;i++){
                x[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            x[indexes[n] - 1].style.display = "block";
        }
```

Haven't tested the code, but should get you there mostly.